# Replacing Multiple Polygon Geometry

Tags: arcmap, polygon, vector

I am carrying out a piece of work in ArcGIS 10.4.1 that involves realigning polygons to an updated vector map. The polygons in question are planning permission boundaries that are created showing the outline of the property the planning permission request refers to. Over a number of years a single property can have had multiple polygons drawn to reflect the different planning applications made against it. These polygons have been drawn by various different people over the years and depending on how accurate they were whilst creating them, they may have missing or extra vertices or no longer match the updated vector map due to changes in the the most recent mapping updates.

I am looking for a quicker way to achieve this than editing the individual polygons. Ideally what I would like to do is define a polygon shape created from my new base map layer and replace the geometry of all the planning permissions in one go. I do not know if this is possible but I have approx 60,000 polygons that potentially need replacing / realigning to new geometry and I cannot see an end in sight doing these individually!

Edited to include screenshot, In this screenshot, the red polygons is the planning layer, I need to align these polygons with the geometry of the green vector map, in this screenshot I have four misdrawn polygons that need to be redrawn to match the green vector map....

[image]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot to make your question easier to understand?